# M3 globular cluster: simple age determination

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-evolution, star-clusters

For my pre-university pupils I would like to find a simple way to determine the age of the globular cluster M3 using a colour-magnitude diagram (CMD, B-V horizontal axis and apparent visual magnitude vertical). Simple: without isochrones etc.
[image]
CMD of M3 (Renzini et al., ARA&A, 26, 199-244)

A simple age determination starts with the main sequence turn-off point at an apparent visual magnitude $m_\textrm{V}=19.1$. The absolute visual magnitude is $M_\textrm{V}=19.1-5\cdot\log\frac{d}{10~\textrm{pc}}=4.015$ with $d=10.4~\textrm{kpc}$. A colour index B-V=0.35 gives a small bolometric correction $\textrm{BC}=0.030$ (Flower, ApJ, 469, 355, table 3; by the way, how can BC be positive?), so the absolute bolometric magnitude is $M_\textrm{bol}=4.045$.

Using $M_\textrm{bol}=M_{\textrm{bol},\odot}-2.5\log\frac{L}{L_\odot}$ and $M_{\textrm{bol},\odot}=4.74$ I find $\frac{L}{L_\odot}=1.897$.

A mass-luminosity relation $\frac{L}{L_\odot}=(\frac{\textrm{mass}}{\textrm{mass}_\odot})^{3.8}$ gives $\frac{\textrm{mass}}{\textrm{mass}_\odot}=1.18$

For a globular cluster a low metallicity $Z=0.002$ seems to be reasonable. Recent models bij Georgy et al. indicate a main sequence lifetime between 3823 Myr (1.10 solar mass) and 2629 Myr (1.25 solar mass, both with rotation, arxiv.org/abs/1308.2914, table 2). This is unrealistic: M3 is aged about 11 Gyr.

For an old globular cluster I would expect stars at the turn-off point with less mass and dimmer than the sun. The sun has a main sequence lifetime of about 9 Gyr, so a turn-off star aged 11 Gy would have less mass and be dimmer than the sun. My mass is 1.18 solar and luminosity is 1.897 times brighter than the sun, contrary to what I expect.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Where does the colour come from? Where does your mass-luminosity relation come from - it isn't the same for metal-rich and metal-poor stars? Is the bolometric correction for metal-poor stars?

Comment: A further issue, and possibly more important, is that a star at the turn-off is probably about twice the luminosity of a zero age main sequence star of the same mass. i.e. Your mass luminosity relation is in error in another respect.

Comment: The colour B-V=0.35 is from the CMD which I've just added, simply estimated on the horizontal axis. My ML-relation is the generic relation; I do not know about another relation for metal-poor stars. BC from Flower's text. He doesn't discriminate for metallicity. I don't know how to quantify the higher luminosity at the turn-off, more so if the mass is still unknown. I apologise for my ignorance, not being an astronomer. Does this mean there is no straight-forward age determination using the turn-off point?

Comment: After some further reading: $L\textrm{~}\mu^{7.5}\cdot M^{5.1}/Z$ for 0.5<M<2$M_\odot$, but only for ZAMS stars...